# dataframe.loc with split string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How can I match an int converted to str in a column using split??

```
personid = '23'
cond = (personid == x for x in df['wait'].str.split(","))
rows = df.loc[cond, :]
```

`df['wait']` contains str like "2,13,23"

Currently it returns `Empty DataFrame`

Comment: Please post sample input data with expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If add `expand=True` to [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) get DataFrame with new columns fileld by splitted values, then compare by `==` by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and test if at least one `True` per row by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html). last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
#personid is string - `''`
personid = '23'
cond = df['wait'].str.split(",", expand=True).eq(personid).any(axis=1)

rows = df[cond]
```

If want match integers values in `personid`:

```
#personid is integer
personid = 23
cond = df['wait'].str.split(",", expand=True).astype(float).eq(personid).any(axis=1)

rows = df[cond]
```

---

Your solution shoud be changed:

```
cond  = [any(y == personid for y in x) for x in df['wait'].str.split(",")]
```

Comment: This works. Could you explain the syntax? Wouldn't matching integers use `int` instead of `float`?